# Angular 2 - How do I navigate to another route using this.router.parent.navigate('/about')?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Angular 2 - How do I navigate to another route using `this.router.parent.navigate('/about')`?

It doesn't seem to work.
I tried `location.go("/about");` as that didn't work.

Basically, once a user has logged in I want to redirect them to another page.

Here is my code below:

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

 import {AuthService} from '../../authService';

 //Model
 class User {
   constructor(public email: string, public password: string) {}
 }

 @Component({
   templateUrl:'src/app/components/todo/todo.html',
   directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
 })

 export class Todo {   
     model = new User('Mark@gmail.com', 'Password'); 
     authService:AuthService;
     router: Router;

   constructor(_router: Router, _authService: AuthService){   
       this.authService = _authService;
       this.router = _router;
   }

   onLogin = () => {
       this.authService.logUserIn(this.model).then((success) => {      

          //This is where its broke - below:          
          this.router.parent.navigate('/about');

       });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Also, I've set the route config in my app.ts file like so:


      @RouteConfig([
       { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
       { path: '/home', component: Todo, as: 'Home' },
       { path: '/about', component: About, as: 'About' }
      ])

Comment: you should remove the `/` in your paths as it isnt required

Answer (score 405, accepted):

**Absolute path routing**

There are 2 methods for navigation, `.navigate()` and `.navigateByUrl()`

You can use the method `.navigateByUrl()` for absolute path routing:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

navigateToLogin() {
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
}
```

You put the absolute path to the URL of the component you want to navigate to.

Note: Always specify the complete absolute path when calling router's `navigateByUrl` method. Absolute paths must start with a leading `/`

```
// Absolute route - Goes up to root level    
this.router.navigate(['/root/child/child']);

// Absolute route - Goes up to root level with route params   
this.router.navigate(['/root/child', crisis.id]);
```

**Relative path routing**

If you want to use relative path routing, use the `.navigate()` method.

NOTE: It's a little unintuitive how the routing works, particularly parent, sibling, and child routes:

```
// Parent route - Goes up one level 
// (notice the how it seems like you're going up 2 levels)
this.router.navigate(['../../parent'], { relativeTo: this.route });

// Sibling route - Stays at the current level and moves laterally, 
// (looks like up to parent then down to sibling)
this.router.navigate(['../sibling'], { relativeTo: this.route });

// Child route - Moves down one level
this.router.navigate(['./child'], { relativeTo: this.route });

// Moves laterally, and also add route parameters
// if you are at the root and crisis.id = 15, will result in '/sibling/15'
this.router.navigate(['../sibling', crisis.id], { relativeTo: this.route });

// Moves laterally, and also add multiple route parameters
// will result in '/sibling;id=15;foo=foo'. 
// Note: this does not produce query string URL notation with ? and & ... instead it
// produces a matrix URL notation, an alternative way to pass parameters in a URL.
this.router.navigate(['../sibling', { id: crisis.id, foo: 'foo' }], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Or if you just need to navigate within the current route path, but to a different route parameter:

```
// If crisis.id has a value of '15'
// This will take you from `/hero` to `/hero/15`
this.router.navigate([crisis.id], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

**Link parameters array**

A link parameters array holds the following ingredients for router navigation:

- The path of the route to the destination component. `['/hero']`
- Required and optional route parameters that go into the route URL. `['/hero', hero.id]` or `['/hero', { id: hero.id, foo: baa }]`

**Directory-like syntax**

The router supports directory-like syntax in a link parameters list to help guide route name lookup:

`./` or no leading slash is relative to the current level.

`../` to go up one level in the route path.

You can combine relative navigation syntax with an ancestor path. If you must navigate to a sibling route, you could use the `../<sibling>` convention to go up one level, then over and down the sibling route path.

**Important notes about relative nagivation**

To navigate a relative path with the `Router.navigate` method, you must supply the `ActivatedRoute` to give the router knowledge of where you are in the current route tree.

After the link parameters array, add an object with a `relativeTo` property set to the `ActivatedRoute`. The router then calculates the target URL based on the active route's location.

From official [Angular Router Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: Mind you if you have children routes:  `{ path: 'home', component: Home, children: homeRoutes }` Then you want to provide that to the router method: `this.router.navigate(['home/address-search'])` OR `this.router.navigateByUrl(/'home/address-search')`

Comment: Even this is a good answer, is important to notice that 
```this.router= Router;``` may confuse some readers, in this case is a mention to a dependency injection of Router, which should me made using this code instead

```constructor( private router: Router ) ```

Comment: @siddharta Thanks for the tip, I did not notice that until you pointed it out. I must have originally written it quickly and intended to update it later but forgot. The example has been updated to use proper dependency injection now.

Answer (score 34):

You should use

```
this.router.parent.navigate(['/About']);
```

As well as specifying the route path, you can also specify your route's name:

```
{ path:'/About', name: 'About',   ... }

this.router.parent.navigate(['About']);
```

Comment: Hi, when I do that I get this error message in my typescript compiler:

"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type any[], Property push is missing in type String"

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work: this.router.parent.navigate('[/About]');

Comment: You should use this syntax: this.router.parent.navigate(['/About']); You have to pass array ['/About'] not string '[/About]'

Comment: For router 3 beta use `this._router.navigate(['/some-route']);`

Answer (score 28):

Also can use without `parent`

say router definition like:

```
{path:'/about',    name: 'About',   component: AboutComponent}
```

then can navigate by `name` instead of `path`

```
goToAboutPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['About']); // here "About" is name not path
}
```

**Updated for V2.3.0**

In Routing from v2.0 **name** property no more exist. route define without **name** property. so you should use **path** instead of **name**. `this.router.navigate(['/path'])` and *no leading slash* for path so use `path: 'about'` instead of `path: '/about'`

router definition like:

```
{path:'about', component: AboutComponent}
```

then can navigate by `path`

```
goToAboutPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['/about']); // here "About" is path
}
```

Comment: ```name``` is deprecated on the Route type in Angular 2.0.

Comment: in Angular 2 `v2.3.0` the `data` shall to be used instead of `name`. For more details -> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 10):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
//in your constructor
constructor(public router: Router){}

//navigation 
link.this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I found that, since we maintain a `ngRoutes` collection (long story) i find the most enjoyment from:

```
GOTO(ri) {
    this.router.navigate(this.ngRoutes[ri]);
}
```

I actually use it as part of one of our interview questions. This way, I can get a near-instant read at who's been developing forever by watching who twitches when they run into `GOTO(1)` for Homepage redirection.

Comment: Arent there something missing here?