# Redirect to another page Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a login page with a form and one button to do the login. When the user click in the button I want to evaluate the password and email and if all is correct the user must be redirected to another page.

My problem is as a I've inside the login html this `(<router-outlet></router-outlet>)` all the information of the new page is showed in the same place of the login page and I don't want to mix both information. I want to have the login separate of the new information.

I try to use window.location.href but doesn't work the information continued to show in the same place of the login.

This is my Route Configuration.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'show_alunos', component: ListAlunosComponent }
];
```

The component ListAlunosComponent is the new page I want to display after validate the credentials of the user.

app.component.html

```
<form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" (click)="submit()" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
mport { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'app';
   public email: string;
   public password: string;

   constructor(private router: Router) {
       this.email = "";
       this.password = "";
    }

   public submit(): void {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(['show_alunos']);
   }
}
```

app.router.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ListAlunosComponent } from '../pages/list-alunos/list-
alunos.component';

// Route Configuration.
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'show_alunos', component: ListAlunosComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Redirect after successful login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479144/angular-2-redirect-after-successful-login-not-working)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After you check e-mail and passwork try:

```
router.navigate(['/show_alunos'])
```

And in constructor declare

```
constructor (private router: Router)
```

And import { Router } from "@angular/router";

UPDATED:

Simple example how to user Ruter:

your.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="Email">
  <input type="password" formContolName="Password">
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

your.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'component-tag-name',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html'
})

export class YourComponentName implements OnInit {

myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(){
 this.myForm = this.FormGroup({
   'Email': new FormConrol(null, [Validators.required]),
   'Password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
  })
}

onSubmit(){
  let email = this.myForm.get('Email').value;
  let password = this.myForm.get('Password').value;

  if (email === 'your value' && password === 'your value'){
    this.router.navigate(['/show_alunos']);
  }   
}
```

In yout app.module.ts you need import this component and ListAlunosComponent too. Then you need import this components and write in your routing config .ts file:

```
{ path: 'show_alunos', component: ListAlunosComponent }
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the point of regurgitating information which is readily available in the easy-to-understand on-line documentation for Angular routing.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Jota Toledo before I ask this question I've read several examples in google but I don't see any example that do what I want

Comment: FierceDev thank you very much for your answer.  I already had all the configuration you said and my configuration work and shows the information about students but is showed in the same place of the login because I've (<router-outlet></router-outlet>) in the code html of the login.

Comment: Your problem solved now? Use router-outlet in main component of your project

Comment: FierceDev are you saing me to put the <router-outlet> here in the file app.component.html?
I was put it here but both information is showed. Maybe in this file I'll need to put only the <router-outlet> and create a component with the form . Because I put the form inside the file app.component.html

Comment: Add to your router config {path: '', component: LoginComponent}. If you going to route like 'localhost:4200' you will redirect to LoginComponent and after youu can reditect in ListAlunosComponent if e-mail and pass success

Comment: FierceDev do you know if is possible to have more than one (<router-outlet></router-outlet>) in other component or only you can have one (<router-outlet></router-outlet>) in all the aplication. Thank you very much

Comment: You don't need more than one outlet, but if u want u can create more modules and route, and your project will more deep, read about Child routes, you can create anoter modules and routes and scale your project. Good luck!!!

Comment: @FierceDev Error is coming while compiling  error TS2339: Property 'FormGroup' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'.
Any Solution for it, Is their ant component need to be install for FormGroup. I am new to angular.