# How to navigate from child component to upper level routes using link params array in angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

My AppComponent has a @RouteConfig decorator that defines the top-level routes:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/profile/...',
    name: 'Profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
])

export class AppComponent {
}
```

My ProfileComponent has a @RouteConfig decorator that defines the Profile child routes:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: ProfileDetailsComponent, name: 'View', useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/:id', component: ProfileDetailsComponent, name: 'Public'},
  {path: '/edit', component: ProfileEditorComponent, name: 'Edit'},
])

export class ProfileComponent {
}
```

When i'm inside ProfileDetailsComponent I can do redirects to other Profile routes but not others. I want to avoid specifying the url using `navigateByUrl` and use route names instead, using `navigate`. E.g.:

```
this.router.navigate(['View']); // Works
this.router.navigate(['About']); // Raises error that it does not exist
```

I read this answer here: [Angular 2 - How to navigate to another route using this.router.parent.navigate('/about')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571605/angular-2-how-to-navigate-to-another-route-using-this-router-parent-navigate)

It uses:

```
this.router.parent.navigate(['About']);
```

Which is sort of ok, but solves my problem only when I know at declaration time where the redirect should go. I have multiple levels of nesting and determine the target route at runtime. I'm looking for a way to do something like:

```
this.router.navigate(['Level1', 'Level2', 'Level3']);
```

Which allows me to track somewhere the fully qualified name of the target route. Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where a microservice comes in handy, check out the [service docs here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service). The idea is that the parent can listen for child requests to navigate and the child can broadcast said changes as desired.

Let's start with a simple object that will store the route name and the optional arguments:

```
export class NavArgs {
   constructor(routeName: string, args?: any) { }
}
```

Now let's define the microservice, with [`rxjs`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) this is really easy:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
  private navigationRequestedSource = new Subject<string>();

  onNavigationRequested$ = this.navigationRequestedSource.asObservable();

  requestNaivation(navArg: string) {
    this.navigationRequestedSource.next(mission)
  }
}
```

Now a child component can consume it and request a navigation:

```
export class SomeChild {
   constructor(navService: NavigationService) { }
   invoke() {
      this.navService.requestNaivation(new NavArgs('SomeRoute'));
   }
}
```

And a parent component can listen for said request and act on it:

```
export class SomeParent {
   constructor(navService: NavigationService, router: Router) {
      this.navService
          .onNavigationRequested$
          .subscribe((navArgs: NavArgs) => {
              if (navArgs) {
                  if (navArgs.args) {
                      this.router.navigate([ navArgs.routeName, navArgs.args ]);
                  }
                  else {
                      this.router.navigate([ navArgs.routeName ]);
                  }
              }
      });
   }       
}
```

Obviously this is the very basic code example, there would need to be more imports and error handling and such. But hopefully you get the idea.

**Note**

It is important to ensure that both the parent and child use the same instance of this service, in order to do that - you must set it as a `provider` at the highest level where it is being used. That is because by default **Angular2** creates a singleton for **DI** and uses a hierarchical approach. You must ensure that you do not mistakenly set it as a `provider` at a lower level, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Like the idea, seems neat and generic as I wanted. Will try it after work and come back with feedback!

Comment: It's probably a good time to upgrade to the new router as well, if you're using the Angular 2 release candidate, as things like route names are now deprecated.

Comment: Awesome this worked great at any combination levels of parent/child components. Thank you!

Comment: I learned angular2 last week for a hackathon so sorry if this sounds silly but what do you mean `new router`? Is it using `Routes` instead of `RouteConfig` cos i've seen that in a couple of blogs..

Comment: @fips, this is referring specifically to **Angular2 RC***, with the scoped approach rather than the bundled.

Answer (score 6):

Prefix the route name with a slash to indicate that the route is a root route

```
this.router.navigate(['/About']);
```

Comment: Do you have any blog posts that you could share that you have authored, I see you all the time on here answering everyone's **Angular2** questions?

Comment: Yep worked! But in my scenario I need the flexibility/abstraction the other solution provides. Thank you!