# location.go() is not redirecting the user in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm making login check. Once that is the success, I want to redirect the user to another page in the same application. I have below code to do that.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
   providers: [Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}],
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],

})
export class LoginComponent   {

static location:Location;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private dataService: DataService,location: Location) {
                LoginComponent.location = location;

      this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    });
  }

  loginForm : FormGroup;
  username = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  password = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

Login(){

  this.dataService.doLogin(this.loginForm.value.username,this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe(function(res){
       console.log(LoginComponent.location)
       LoginComponent.location.go('/report');
     },function(err){
        console.log("Err",err)
      });;
}
```

}

But the issue is, URL in browser changed to http://localhost:3000/report. But when the page is not loading. When I hit reload, then the new page is getting displayed.

What is wrong in this code? `location.go()` won't load the URL.

Comment: I think you should use `router` for redirects, do you use `routing`?

Comment: Yes. Router worked for me. I have referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571605/angular-2-how-to-navigate-to-another-route-using-this-router-parent-navigate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use angular router, then use Router class which is located at angular/router namespace. 
Take a look at this
[Angular Router Navigation example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#navigate).
I think that will help to solve your problem.
[Location class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html) is meant to interact with URL, but not navigate in application routes (as it did in angular 1).

Quote from that article about Location class:"

> Note: it's better to use Router service to trigger route changes. Use Location only if you need to interact with or create normalized URLs outside of routing.