# Angular2 Router Navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, web, routes

I'm trying to test out router navigation in my application, however each time I attempt to navigate to my url I get thrown back to the homepage.

The router should navigate to the next page when the user selects a row to complete a form, like this:

```
  onUserRowSelect(event): void {
    this.router.navigate(['myform']);}
```

However, myforms is not being navigated to, heres how I defined the routes:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserAdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'createuser',
        component: CreateUserComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'updateuser',
        component: UpdateUserComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'myform',
            component: UpdateFormComponent,
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
```

];

So the navigate to `myURL/useradmin/updateuser/myform` does not work at all (if the child routes are working even).

I can elaborate more if needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to navigate to a child route of the current route (e.g. from `updateuser` to `updateuser/myform`), you can use relative navigation:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { 
}

onUserRowSelect(event): void {
    this.router.navigate(['./myform'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

You can find many more navigation cases in [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37622179/1009922) by [TetraDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5376813/tetradev).

---

**Update**: if the `UpdateFormComponent` is to replace the `UpdateUserComponent` when navigating, then they should both be direct children of `UserAdminComponent`:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserAdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'createuser',
        component: CreateUserComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'updateuser',
        component: UpdateUserComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'myform',
        component: UpdateFormComponent
      }
    ]
  }];
```

and the navigation would be perform this way:

```
onUserRowSelect(event): void {
    this.router.navigate(['../myform'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, the url changed but the component did not render.

Comment: How do you export/import these routes? Do you use `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` (see [this article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-component-router#routermoduleforchild))? Can you show that code in the question?

Comment: in the same routing component: export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);

Comment: And you import these routes in the component's module?

Comment: Its a bit complicated, I will prepare a plunkr for visibility.

Comment: By the way, do you have a `router-outlet` in your template?

Comment: Yeah I do, the problem now is the component is rendering on top of the other instead of replacing it.

Comment: Since `myform` is a child `updateuser`, it will appear on top of it. If you want to replace it, they should be "brothers", both children of `UserAdminComponent`.

Comment: oh ok, I'll try that then. But is not possible to redirect to Forms page without being brothers? Since my concept is: Navigate to List of Users, then select a user to edit their information. What I'm trying to get is to render a page to edit the user information.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the two components as brothers. I am not sure how this will integrate in the design of your application, but you can experiment with the two configurations: components as parent/child or as brothers.

Comment: it worked, thank you very much! So this is the only case of rendering components? child of child components cannot render each other?

Comment: I don't know all the possibilities but I always envisioned a child as rendered in a `router-outlet` of its parent. Glad to know that it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the complete path starting from the parent

```
   this.router.navigate(['useradmin','updateuser','myform']);}
```