# navigate or navigateByUrl from within component in ng 5

Tags: angular

I am using an admin dashboard that has a file structure with authguard and all. I can create links with [routeLink] from templates fine but no matter which combination I try, I have failed to do from route.navigate (or naviateByUrl).

There is an excellent intro here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571605/angular-2-how-to-navigate-to-another-route-using-this-router-parent-navigate) but am failing still.
Not sure if the file structure is necessary but just to give any idea:

I have layouts module that contains routing directions:

```
    { path: 'logistics', loadChildren: './logistics/logistics.module#LogisticsModule' },
```

where logistics is a module within the layout module. Under it, there are several other componenets. I access them with localhost:4200/logistics/new

for e.g. to create a new logistic data. Now from that component, I want to navigate to

localhost:4200/logistics/print/2

where 2 is id of the new transaction to be printed. They are both within the same directory and parent route.

The following don't work:

```
   this.route.navigate(['/logistics/print',2])
   this.route.navigate(['logistics/print',2])
   this.route.navigateByUrl('logistics/print/2')
```

I did come across { relativeTo: this.route } but I think I have failed to apply it properly as it made no difference.

Comment: Just to be sure: `this.route` is an instance of Router? the relativeTo options needs an instance of ActivatedRoute

Comment: public router: Router. I have actually thot of ActivatedRoute too but it tells me router does not have .navgiate method if router is ActivatedRoute