# Switch to another angular view in controller

Tags: angularjs

Is possible to switch to another angular view in controller? I meant something like this:

```
function ItemController($http, $routeParams) {
   $http.get('/api/item/' + $routeParams.ItemId).then(function(response) {
       self.related_item = response.data['related_item_id'];
       if (self.related_item != 10) {
           switch_to_another_view('#!/items/' + self.related_item);
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: $location.path(view); you can use

Comment: Maybe this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571605/angular-2-how-to-navigate-to-another-route-using-this-router-parent-navigate

Comment: If you are using ui-router or $stateProvider, do it as: $state.go('stateName');

Comment: @Saniyasyedqureshi I'm using ngRoute, angular 1.6

Comment: Try using $location.path(view);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using  angular-router or $routeProvider, do it as:

```
$location.path('items')
```