# Navigating to a new page in angular not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im new to angular and i have created website using angular. When i Login it shows the username in the top of the page(shown below)

[image]

my requirement is, when i click it i want to take the user to another(for example user details page) But what i have done in my .html and .ts files doesnt do anything

The relevant html code part

```
<div class="m-2"> 
<i class="fa cursor-pointer" (click)="Navigatekbuttonclick($event)">{{username}}</i>
</div>
```

the relevant .ts part

```
Navigatekbuttonclick(){
this.router.navigate([/userdetails]);
}
```

Can anybody help on this navigation part please and tell me whats missing

Comment: You forgot ''s : this.router.navigate(['/userdetails]'); ?

Comment: thanks buddy but still no good!!! some developers say theres a long proceedure called modifying routes..do u have any idea about that??

Answer (score 0):

The path you passing in parameters needs to be in quotation marks.

Try this:

```
Navigatekbuttonclick(){
this.router.navigate(['/userdetails']);
}
```

But in order for that to work, you must define the route in your router :

```
{path:'/userdetails', component: userDetailComponent}
```

Here's a link that can help you : [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: OP already mentioned that it did not help... issue is something else it seems

Comment: what are the scripts i should define the above three? :)

Comment: @Prog_Rookie The same question has been answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571605/angular-2-how-to-navigate-to-another-route-using-this-router-parent-navigate