# Angular 6 routing redirected to original component as the url is not found

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, angular-router

I am having a problem with routing. I am at the unit component adding a new unit to my database. The url is like the following:

> http://localhost:4200/dashboard/registration/unit

When the insert to my database is successful, the id is sent back from PHP to the `.subscribe()` method:

```
 .subscribe(
    (data)=>{
      console.log(data);

      //this.router.navigate(['unit/addH/'+data]);

    },
    (error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    }
  )
```

I need to redirect into another component directly, taking the id returned with me through the url:

```
 .subscribe(
    (data)=>{
      console.log(data);

      this.router.navigate(['unit/addH/'+data]);

    },
    (error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    }
  )
```

So the data available  at the console, but when redirected, it took me to the initial component as the path is not recognized.

Here is the routing paths:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegistrationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'unit',
    component: UnitComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'unit/:unit_id',
    component: UnitEditComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'unit/addH/:uid',
    component: AddHComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'registration',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

I tried to use the `queryParams`:

```
this.router.navigate(['unit/addH', {queryParams: {unit_id: data}}]);
```

But still redirect to `registration component.

Please note that there is no errors at the console.

[image]

At the network tab:

[image]

**EDIT**

Full routing script:

The first routing module (Parent):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot',
    component: ForgotPasswordComponent
    //canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path:'dashboard',
    loadChildren: '../app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'

  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The dashboard module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path:'',
        component: HomeComponent  
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './main-navbar/main-navbar.module#MainNavbarModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'registration',
        loadChildren: './registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    path:'**',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

The registration module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration.component';
import { UnitComponent } from './unit/unit.component';
import { UnitEditComponent } from './unit/unit-edit/unit-edit.component';
import { AddHouseholdComponent } from './unit/add-household/add-household.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegistrationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'unit',
    component: UnitComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'unit/:unit_id',
    component: UnitEditComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'unit/addH/:uid',
    component: AddHouseholdComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'registration',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RegistrationRoutingModule { }
```

I am being redirected to the login component.

Comment: putting a forward slash before your route might solve your issue,

this.router.navigate(['/unit/addH/'+data]);

Comment: Nope. It still redirecting to parent component.

Comment: from which route you are navigating to this route, means what is your active route when you navigate to this route?

Comment: `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/registration/unit`

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? I can look into it.

Comment: Is the returned `data` a string? If so, have you tried `this.router.navigate(['/unit/addH', data]);`

Comment: Also, you can enable router stack tracing to make your life easier when debugging routing issues. 

`imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }) ],`

Comment: show us `console.log(data)`

Comment: The returned data is from PHP as JSON and it is an integer displayed at the console as `"153"` per example

Comment: please show us the console Screen shot if possible

Comment: @Exterminator okay give me one minute to edit the post

Comment: Okay you can now check it. @WasifAle I will do a fiddle in the afternoon and send you the link, if no one solve it.

Comment: @droidnation sure thing :)

Comment: So what you are getting here is a string, not an integer

Comment: @Exterminator yes, because at the server side I am sending it as `json_encode($res)`

Comment: Guys I've added all routing scripts at the end of the question. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to convert that string into integer using `parseInt()` function then you can use the following method

```
let id= parseInt(data);
this.router.navigate(['unit/addH', id]);
```

OR

```
this.router.navigate(['/unit/addH', id]);
```

Hope this helps.

Trying defining the routes in such a way

```
 {
 path: 'unit', component: UnitComponent
        children: [
            {path: '', component: UnitComponent},
            {path: 'unit/:unit_id', component: UnitEditComponent},
            {path: 'unit/addH/:id', component: AddHouseholdComponent}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: `[ts] Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` so it is giving me error on `data` saying it is an object and can't convert it

Comment: try using `(data: any)=>{}` or `JSON.stringify(data)` will work

Comment: Okay, give me one minute

Comment: I posted all my routing modules ( I am using lazy loading). You can check them at then end of my question.

Comment: Please note that I am able to access the addH/id by writing it manually

Comment: Did you check your current route? Have tried removing unit from the first argument?

Comment: Try this.router.navigate([this.router.url + '/addH', id]);
Log this.router.url to see where you are.

Comment: check the route i define and use it

Comment: and also there is no need of defining `path: '**'` part as well

Comment: Both `{path: 'unit/:unit_id', component: UnitEditComponent},
            {path: 'unit/addH/:id', component: AddHouseholdComponent}` redirecting me to the parent component `dashboardComponent`

Comment: You can access my computer using teamviewer guys

Comment: I can help with that but in the evening time. I guess problem here is that you are using multiple modules, so it is not able to get the route file of rest of the modules

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that you want to navigate to a relative route where you call `router.navigate`.  It should look like this:

```
    this.router.navigate(['addH', id],{relativeTo:this.route});
```

This will mean that you are navigating to:
`http://localhost:4200/dashboard/registration/unit/addH/??`
Instead of navigating to:
`http://localhost:4200/unit/addH/??`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was by adding an absolute path when using `navigate()`:

> this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/registration/unit/addHH',
>   id]);

For a detailed answer on each type of navigation and which path to be used when working with different navigation methods, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571605/angular-2-how-to-navigate-to-another-route-using-this-router-parent-navigate?answertab=active#tab-top) on stack overflow, at which, the user explained it as following:

> You put the absolute path to the URL of the component you want to
>   navigate to.
>
> Note: Always specify the complete absolute path when calling router's
>   navigateByUrl method. Absolute paths must start with a leading /
>
> `// Absolute route - Goes up to root level`
>   `this.router.navigate(['/root/child/child']);`
>
> `// Absolute route - Goes up to root level with route params`
>   `this.router.navigate(['/root/child', crisis.id]);`