# How do I string a relative path

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to create a link for users to click on to verify their e-mail. To do that I would need to create the link. How do I convert a `this.router` to string? I would also need to retrieve the user's user id. If that is not possible, can I create a string that passes in the relative path?

I tried this:

```
let loginRoute = this.router.navigateByUrl("./login", {
      queryParams: { key: data.id }
});
```

but obviously it does not work since it `.navigateByUrl` returns a boolean result.

Comment: What have you done so far. Show me the code

Comment: @TonyNgo added the code

Comment: you can use ActivatedRoute.params then subscribe parameter from ur router.

Comment: @Nuttertools can you post the answer?

Comment: Answer in the below link might help solve your issue!
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37622179/9997860)

Comment: @Thivagar i do not want to navigate to the page. what i would like to do is to get the relative path and convert it to a string

Comment: you want string URL with user id like this http://example.com/user/10, Right?

Comment: @skdroid yes correct

Answer (score 1):

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id'];
    });
```

This can get you the id in the query param.

If you want the domain, please do this -

```
const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
const baseUrl = parsedUrl.origin;
console.log(baseUrl);
```

Comment: what would be the datatypes for `this.sub` and `this.id`? i'm getting errors where i need to convert them to string

Comment: id: number;
sub: Subscription

Answer (score 1):

Use `DOCUMENT` and `Router` to make the URL String with Params.

import DOCUMENT into a component from `platform-browser` and Router form @angular/router

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Initialize constructor

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any
  ) {}
```

make URL using

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let domain = this.document.location.hostname;
    this.href = this.router.url;
    console.log(domain+this.href)
  }
```

Working Sample - [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/skdroid-routing) code is in the child-one component

---

**------------ EDITED AFTER COMMENTS -------------**

use DOCUMENT to get domain/hostname and concat parameters to that domain.

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
        private route:ActivatedRoute

      ) {}

ngOnInit() {
        let domain = this.document.location.hostname;
        let userId = this.route.snapshot.params['userId'];
        console.log(domain+'?user='+userId)
      }
```

Comment: i dont think this solution works. this uses the current url. for my case, I would like to convert a relative path (not the current url) into a string, whilst adding the user's id at the back

Comment: i am doing this in my authentication service. after adding the data to database, i will get the id created as my parameters

Comment: can you post an example URL which you are trying to create? and also parameter getting via service

Comment: the example: http://localhost:4200/login?uid=<user's uid>. this is in the developer mode so when i go to the live website, it needs to change to website.com/login?uid=<user's id>. hence why i would like to string a relative path

Comment: so basically you just want a current domain name and you already know how to get other parameters like /login?uid=<user-id>

Comment: for that, you can use DOCUMENT as in answer to get a current domain name, for example, if the current server is localhost then this.document.location.hostname returns localhost:4200 and in the server, it returns website.com and concat parameters and generates URL.