# RouterLink work but function with router.navigate dont

Tags: angular

My routerlink is working but after trying to convert it to a function it just does nothing. I have tried many things already: `'/description'` `'description'` `'/description/'`.

before:

```
  <a [routerLink]="['description', course.id]">Go to description</a>
```

After (.html):

```
  <a (click)="goToDescription(course.id)">Go to description</a>
```

After (.ts):

```
  goToDescription(id) {
    this.router.navigate([`description`, id]);
  }
```

Route Description:

```
  {
    path: 'description/:course-id', component: CourseDescriptionComponent,
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571605/angular-2-how-to-navigate-to-another-route-using-this-router-parent-navigate

Comment: One concern I'd have is that `<a>` is being used with onclick rather than routerLink/href in addition to no preventDefault() occurring in the handler.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I can change to div/button/whatever but the error continues ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the absolute url and it worked thanks to @Kamil Augustyniak who sent a link that helped me

```
  this.router.navigateByUrl(`/courses/description/${id}`);
```